# Бэкап mysql на kvm гипервизоре

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, резервное-копирование, kvm

Допустим, существует некий centos7 сервер с libvirt (*гипервизор*). На этом сервере запущена виртуальная машина (*гость*) в которую проброшен **lvm-раздел** с *гипервизора* определяющийся на *госте* как **vdb**. На *госте* запущен **mysql-server-5.7** и подлинно известно, что он работает с БД которая расположена на разделе смонтированном на **vdb**. В остальном гость для меня - это чёрный ящик без доступов.

Собственно вопрос: Существует ли наиболее правильный способ, бэкапить **lvm-раздел** на гипервизоре зная, что на госте он смонтирован и на нём находится mysql БД под нагрузкой. Высшая цель - бэкап БД не имея никакого доступа к гостю.

Comment: mysql не сбросит всякие свои буферы на диск без выключения или специальной командой, поэтому, делая бэкап без залезания в гостя, вы рискуете с очень высокой вероятностью получить битую базу

Comment: @andreymal я бы не сказал что совсем битую. Шанс есть, но он не большой. Состояние базы будет такое же как при аварийном выключении.

Comment: @eri такое же, то есть битое :) Мне уже доводилось пару раз бить базы аварийным выключением.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так. Делаем снапшот lvm и получается новое блочное устройство. Монтируешь его. Возможно понадобится kpartx или расчитать offset для монтирования. Забираешь файлы базы. Размонтируешь и удаляешь снапшот.

Comment: Тоже про это думал. К сожалению, не знаком с механизмом клонирования lvm, но мне кажется, что в основе разбитие на чанки и побайтовое копирование, если это так, то чем такой вариант лучше, например DRBD ? В общем, наверно, надо попробовать. Запустить какой-нить mysql-benchmark и посмотреть что будет происходить.

Comment: Так это без доступа к ящику. Просто тащишь ibdata)) Пример команд завтра допишу.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем без доступов сделать вы не сможете. Для бэкапов `mysql` под нагрузкой желательно чтобы тип таблиц был `innodb` тогда можно использовать [`PerconaXtraBackup`](https://ruhighload.com/xtrabackup+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2+mysql). На госте один раз его настраиваете и он будет вам бэкапить куда нужно БД. Вот [неплохой мануал](https://ruhighload.com/xtrabackup+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2+mysql) по PerconaXtraBackup.

Comment: Сможет) смотри мой ответ

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного) Существует лишь задача и объективное кол-во человекочасов на её решение)